# How to make loaded widgets scrollable in RecycleView with RecycleGridLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a `RecycleView` with a `RecycleGridLayout` that loads a bunch of buttons.  But for some reason the loaded widgets will not scroll.

I have tried removing the `size_hint` as well as default widths and heights with no joy.

```
            RecycleView:
                id: view_button
                viewclass: 'Button'
                pos_hint: {'top': 0.90}
                do_scroll_x: True
                do_scroll_y: True
                RecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 1
                    spacing: 1
                    default_size: None, None
                    default_size_hint: None, None
                    height: Window.height
```

Can someone please help me to make them scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I couldn't find it in the documentation, I believe that `default_size` and `default_size_hint` refer to the size of the `viewclass` (in your case `Button`). In order to get the scrolling to work, you need to set `RecycleGridLayout` properties `size_hint` to `None` for the axes that you want to scroll, and set the actual size to something bigger than the containing `RecycleView`. Try replacing

```
height: Window.height
```

with

```
size_hint: None, None
size: self.minimum_size
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you that solved it. To make the ```Buttons``` span the x axis I had to set the ```size_hint: 1, None``` of the ```RecycleGridLayout``` and to ensure I can see all the ```Buttons``` I had to set the ```RecyceView``` y axis the same as the ```pos_hint``` beginning point i.e. ```size_hint: [1, 0.89]```.   I only want to scroll on the y axis.

Comment: If you only want to scroll the y axis, just use `size_hint_y: None` and `height: self.minimum_height` in the `RecycleGridLayout`. And do `do_scroll_x: False` in the `RecycleView`.

Comment: Thanks again.  Interestingly, both your answer and comment solved my question in that with ```size: self.minimum_size``` and ```height: self.minimum_height``` the scroll was possible on the Y-axis.  As long as the ```size_hint``` of the Y-axis was set to ```None```.

Comment: Hi, curiously, it doesn't have much to do with the automa as it deals with RecycleView I think maybe I can find what I'm looking for.

The dimensions of the image are bigger than the widget, I'm freaking out for not being able to make the images sized according to the size of the widget.

Can someone help me?

Below my code:

https://gist.github.com/CoutinhoElias/b502b468d858182690d31716e608c88d

Comment: @EliasCoutinho  If you have a question, you should post a question, not comment on another question.

Comment: My question is related to this matter.
If you don't want to answer, ignore it!